# I-7051(D) ICP DAS - кто знает команды?

Tags: железо

Есть [датчик](http://www.icp-das.ru/catalog/remote_i_o/i-7000_m-7000_tm/i-7000/i-7000_di_dc/27778.html). Документашку дели куда-то. Кто знает, какие команды посылать на прибор?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[А на оф. сайте посмотреть?](http://f.icp-das.ru/files/add/doc/147271/I7000DIO-rus.pdf)